# XML base to Dynamic php page

Tags: php, xml

I'd like some information about creating a php page with some information from a generate xml from a "todolist progam".

Here is the XML generated :

```
<TODOLIST PROJECTNAME="" FILEFORMAT="9" EARLIESTDUEDATE="0.00000000" LASTMOD="41674.63037037" LASTMODSTRING="04/02/2014 15:07" NEXTUNIQUEID="4" FILENAME="tasks.xml" FILEVERSION="2" APPVER="6.8.8.0">
```

The problem is, it generates an XML with `<TASK TITLE (ETC) />` and not `<TASK> <TITLE></TASK> </TITLE>`

and and can't find a solution scripted with this form of XML. I found a script on w3schools.com but the XML is generated differently.

I'd like to know what to do ?

THANKS ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This manual should be a great benefit for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

**Sample XML:**

```
<tasks>
    <task id="1" title="feed the dog" status="0" owner="Tom" />
    <task id="2" title="learn simplexml" status="10" owner="user3271431"/>
</tasks>
```

The task-nodes have *attributes*, e.g. id, title, status etc.

**Create a simplexml-object:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming the XML is in $x
```

**Echo out all tasks:**

```
foreach ($xml->task as $task)
    echo $task['title'] . "(" . $task['id'] . ")" . PHP_EOL;
```

**Select and echo tasks with `owner = Tom`:

```
$tomstasks = $xml->xpath("/tasks/task[@owner = 'Tom']");

foreach ($tomstasks as $task)
    echo "Toms task: " . $task['title'] . PHP_EOL;
```

see it working: https://eval.in/97975